# magento 2.4 what are coupon modifiers?

Tags: checkout, magento2.4, coupon

I'm looking at `Magento\SalesRule\view\frontend\web\js\action\set-coupon-code.js` and on line 47 there's this code:

```
 //Allowing to modify coupon-apply request
 dataModifiers.forEach(function (modifier) {
    modifier(headers, data);
 });
```

I was wondering what those dataModifiers are and how can be used.. I tried searching online but couldn't find any info

Answer (score 0):

That’s functionality for allowing other components to modify the headers and send custom data when calling the “apply coupon code” action. See this [method below](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-coupon-code.js#L91-L98):

```
/**
 * Modifying data to be sent.
 *
 * @param {Function} modifier
 */
action.registerDataModifier = function (modifier) {
    dataModifiers.push(modifier);
};
```

So another component might register a modifier like this:

```
define(['Magento_SalesRule/js/action/set-coupon-code'], function (setCouponCodeAction) {
    'use strict';

    setCouponCodeAction.registerDataModifier(function (headers, data) {
        headers['X-Custom-Header'] = 'foobar';
        data['foo'] = 'bar';
    });
});
```

This will cause those to be sent in the [subsequent REST request](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4/app/code/Magento/SalesRule/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-coupon-code.js#L52-L58):

```
storage.put(
    url,
    data,
    false,
    null,
    headers
)
```